# Platform independent way of doing a touch on a file?

Tags: language-agnostic, cross-platform, touch

How could a platform independent touch be achieved, without using the actual `touch` executable? I cannot rely on `touch` being in PATH, or even existing on a particular system.

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty file and copy the original file + the empty file back to the original file. I just tested it on Windows and it worked.

```
C:\tmp>dir \utils\emp*
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BC80-0D15

 Directory of C:\utils

2011-03-14  11:58                 0 empty_file
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  27,506,368,512 bytes free

C:\tmp>dir *.gif
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BC80-0D15

 Directory of C:\tmp

2010-10-08  12:00            20,463 cknight.gif
2009-10-30  17:31         1,298,525 img-big.gif
2009-10-30  17:46           225,992 img.gif
               3 File(s)      1,544,980 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  27,506,368,512 bytes free

C:\tmp>copy /b img.gif+\Utils\empty_file /b img.gif
img.gif
\Utils\empty_file
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\tmp>dir *.gif
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BC80-0D15

 Directory of C:\tmp

2010-10-08  12:00            20,463 cknight.gif
2009-10-30  17:31         1,298,525 img-big.gif
2011-03-14  12:07           225,992 img.gif
               3 File(s)      1,544,980 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  27,506,368,512 bytes free

C:\tmp>
```

Comment: I think that by running `touch` without arguments, it modifies the last modified timestamp. This is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

touch is a pretty simple program.  You could easily extract the essential steps and implement them as a subroutine in your system.  See [the source code](http://www.koders.com/c/fid96336B4591FD0C5D2C4DADA2D264D3A04F21A934.aspx).

touch depends on `utime()`, which is POSIX and should be available on most platforms.

Alternatively, you could just provide your own touch implementation as an executable (if you need to call it from a script).